# Please explain this logic

Tags: python, for-loop

Please explain why this code can lead this output..

First of all:

```
str1 = 'AB'
str2 = '34'
```

The code is:

```
[y + x for y in str1 for x in str2]
```

And output is:

```
['A3', 'A4', 'B3', 'B4']
```

I don't understand why this code can lead this output.

Comment: Could you maybe tell us which programming language this is and improve the title a bit to make your question easier to find? Thank you :-).

Answer (score 1):

The code is the same as running two nested for loops and inserting each iteration (x + y) to the list. In your example it would be expanded to look like this:

```
str1 = 'AB' 
str2 = '34'

list = []  # Initialize empty list
for y in str1:  # Loop through each character in str1
    for x in str2:  # Loop through each character in str2
        list.append[y + x]  # Add character y and character x to the list

print(list)  # Shows the output of this list
```